# separate using regular expression on a data set PYTHON

Tags: python, regex, twitter, dataset

hi i was hoping if someone can help me , i was trying to cluster data set that consists of tweets of health care of several news channel (e.g bbc, cnn , everydayhealth, foxnewshealth, gdnhealthcare, goodhealth, KaiserHealthNews, latimeshealth, msnhealthnews, NBChealth, nprhealth, nytimeshealth, reuters_health, usnewshealth, wsjhealth)

now the data set is separated by `|`, but this symbol is repeated two time before the tweet is presented, for example a sample from the data set:

```
585978391360221184|Thu Apr 09 01:31:50 +0000 2015|Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF
```

using regular expression i was able to separate each of the previous line with the `|` but i remove the first 2 parameters and keep the tweet to use it in clustering. i was able to find a code that separates the first 2 parameters

```
import re
x = "585978391360221184|Thu Apr 09 01:31:50 +0000 2015|Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF"
d = print(re.split('\|', x).pop(-1))
```

and it provided the output i needed

```
Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF
```

however, when when i applied it on the entire data set it came with this output; it is sort of a collection of the tweets from the news agencies files:

```
["C. diff 'manslaughter' inquiry call  ", 'Health Canada to stop sales of small magnets ', "Robin Roberts' cancer diagnosis ", 'Americans die sooner and are sicker than those in other high-income countries. Does this worry you? ', 'Clinton Kelly’s fresh and
#fruity take on #holiday dishes   #HappyThanksgiving', '"The biggest challenge facing my department, but also the NHS as a whole, is the lack of money." ', 'RT @MSNHealth: The Mediterranean? The Volumetrics? Or maybe the DASH? U.S. Newsâ€™ Best Overall Diet Plans of 2011: ', "Health law's promise of coverage not resonating with Miami's uninsured. ", 'O.B. Ultra tampons are coming back, and the company apologizes with a song ', 'Mental Illness Affects Women, Men Differently, Study Finds: ', "Why it's so hard to get the flu vaccine supply right ", 'Infection Risk Prompts New York City To Regulate Ritual Circumcision ', 'The Doctorâ€™s World: Link to Ethical Scandals Tarnishes Prestigious Parran Award', 'New York lawmakers announce measures to confront heroin epidemic ', "RT @leonardkl: Are you getting #healthinsurance for the first time beginning Jan. 1? I'd love to interview you for a @usnews story! Let me â€¦\n", 'For Desperate Family in India, a Ray of Hope From Alabama ']
```

ps(please note their were shortened URLs after each tweet but i couldn't post them)

this is the code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import re
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
import numpy as np

import glob
import os


file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "E:/Health-News-Tweets/Health-Tweets", "*.txt"))

corpus = []
labels = ["bbchealth","cbchealth","cnnhealth","everydayhealth","foxnewshealth","gdnhealthcare","goodhealth","KaiserHealthNews","latimeshealth"
          ,"msnhealthnews","NBChealth","nprhealth","nytimeshealth","reuters_health","usnewshealth","wsjhealth"]

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path,'r') as f_input:
        data = f_input.read()
        x = re.split('\|', data).pop(-1)
        corpus.append(x)

print(corpus)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

true_k = 16
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10,random_state=3425)
model.fit(X)

Y = vectorizer.transform(["An abundance of online info can turn us into e-hypochondriacs. Or, worse, lead us to neglect getting the care we need"])
prediction = model.predict(Y)

#print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
#print("terms",terms)
for i in range(true_k):
    #print("Cluster %d:" % i)
    if(prediction == i):
        print("The predicted cluster",labels[i])
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
         print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    #print
#print(prediction)
    #  for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        #print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
  #  print
```

my questions here, how can i seprate the first two parameters(just to e clear i have 16  health news channels which are the label of the clusters) and how to apply it to the entire 16 files.

Comment: Why do you need to use `re`? It's just a literal string, not a regular expression pattern, so just use `x.split('|')`

Comment: What's wrong with the output you got?

Comment: @Barmar the reason i used the re is that the need to remove the first 2 parameters. as for your second question, what's wrong with the output is that this isn't the full output of all 16 files; as well as the output is separated the way i intend it to be.

Comment: Doesn't it work the same way with `x.split('|').pop(-1)`?

Comment: @Barmar it  would return with the same output.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: okay, for example a line inside the data set is like this (585978391360221184|Thu Apr 09 01:31:50 +0000 2015|Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF) and how i wanted it to be after applying the separator on it is (Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF ) @Barmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171035/discussion-between-barmar-and-mariam-mohie-sleem).